# Meteor won't start, npm shrinkwrap fails

Tags: meteor, npm

So I'm trying to run [a simple boilerplate app](https://github.com/andyp22/meteor-bone/), but as soon as I start meteor

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Meteor 0.8.0.1 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.     
npm: updating npm dependencies -- async, xml2js...
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/Whit/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/Whit/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/bin/node" "/Users/Whit/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/bin/npm" "shrinkwrap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Whit/Programming/mrt2/meteor-bone/packages/npm/.npm/package-new-1767w7f
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /Users/Whit/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Whit/Programming/mrt2/meteor-bone/packages/npm/.npm/package-new-1767w7f/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `npm`:
error: couldn't run `npm shrinkwrap`
```

Creating a new app and running meteor works fine, though, as does deleting the contents of package.json after manually installing the packages and then running.

So what's going on? Do I have another version of npm that meteor runs? (EDIT: After looking around it appears that meteor keeps its own version of npm to work with, so this was a red herring.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Meteor uses its own version of npm. I doubt your problem is in the wrong npm version, there must be something about your packages